# Can't get random file with random type from folder

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was coding this command for my discord bot, but I tried to fix that lot of times, I already spend 2 hours trying to code but all I get is a **Can't send a empty message** in console

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    name: 'name',
    description: 'description',
    aliases: ['aliase1','aliase2'],
    usage: '[command]',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message) {
        const fileType = ['png','jpg','gif','mp4','mov'];
        const Rfile2 = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/Database`).filter(file => file.endsWith(fileType));
        for (const file of Rfile2) {
            const Rfile = require(`.commands/Database/${file}`)
            const randomFile = Rfile(Math.floor(Math.random()*5) * Rfile.length);
        }
        try {
            message.channel.send(randomFile);
        } catch (error) {
            message.channel.send(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @a.mola I think that helps but it still giving me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String.prototype.endsWith` function expects a string or an array of only one item. So you're passing a whole array which will always return false, Hence filtering out an empty array.

You can `split` the string by all occurrences of the period `.` then `pop` the last character element and then check if the `extension` is included in the `fileType` array

```
const Rfile2 = fs.readdirSync('./commands/Database').filter(file => fileType.includes(file.split('.').pop())));
```

Consider learning Typescript that way you can catch and prevent simple bugs even before you run the code.